# How to increment number with different endianess?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, endianness

I am doing some micro-controller programming where I have to load the firmware of a DSP chip at run time. The DSP chip requires that the register addresses be written in a different endianess so the addres `1024` becomes `0x04, 0x00`. I have the address in a 2 element  `uint8_t` array with the most significant byte being the 0 position and least significant byte being the 1 position. However, I need to run through a loop where i increment each register address by one every iteration. The micro controller is a different endianess so I can't simply cast the array to `uint16_t*` and increment.

How would i go about incrementing the address?

Comment: Can't you just index the array backwards??

Answer (score 3):

I would use a normal int counter, and then convert to the correct endianness before sending it to the DSP. You can use macros in the [byteorder](http://linux.die.net/man/3/byteorder) or [endian](http://linux.die.net/man/3/endian) family. This will be easier to debug and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are looking for from us?

```
1) swap before sending
2) increment the lower byte, add the carry to the upper byte (asm makes this easy)
3) endian swap and increment (x=(upper<<8)|lower; x++)
```